# Mysql how to backup and restore after version 5.5

Tags: mysql, backup, restore

The mySQL manual says that backup and restore are deprecated, and removed in version 5.5.

I have ISAM tables dumped with "backup" from an earlier version (5.0) - how can I restore these to a 5.5+ mySQL database.

Comment: We have been using "backup table tablelist" as an SQL statement via the mySQL ADO.Net driver to automate backups programmatically. There does not seem to be an alternative with 5.5 or later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont mean to sound snarky, but older versions of mysql can be obtained.  Why not install a copy of the older version of mysql, export to SQL using mysqldump, then reimport into a newer version.

Perhaps use a virtual machine inside Virtualbox.

Comment: Thanks, the best way I found to handle it was to have both versions installed and toggle between them by starting/stopping the relevant mySQL services.

Answer (score 1):

I would copy the `*.MYD` and `*.frm` files into the target database directory, and then run a `REPAIR TABLE` on each table (so as to rebuild the indexes).

The "target database directory" is `datadir/dbname` where `datadir` is a server parameter, and `dbname` is your target database name.

`datadir` is found with the SQL command `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';`.

Comment: Doing a simple copy from the pre-5.5 backup files (.myd and .frm) does not work. MySQL doesn't recognise the tables when trying to open (e.g file "tableName" not found) although the tables are listed (using Navicat). Repair table gives the same error.